# sha256sum mismatch in cloud images

Tags: 16.04, cloud, tar, sha256

Is anyone having issues with the 6/20 build?

http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz

We have an automated process which downloads images. First the sha256sum check passed but we saw unexpected EOF errors when trying to untar the file.  Later we were able to download and untar the file but the sha256sum does not match.

From the sha256sums file.

```
7584d5214285c249a9ae80f98b71d7cc216fd915be2ca40d82a1e4603b7ae257 *xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz
```

Output in terminal

```
sha256sum  xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz
04f9bd06a12636ac1e747856de2797a8a17c8ebcfca4714c080912bff90eeca1  xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz
```

I suspect the file may have been replaced but the sha256sum value not updated?

Comment: It happens on multiple systems, so it is not isolated.

Comment: The automated process we are using has been in place for months with no recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

That is very possible. Things like that happen not just with Ubuntu, but with other packages and operating systems. But first:

1. **Be 100% sure that it is downloading properly.** Try on other machines, and if possible another network. A lot of these errors actually occur because it isn't downloading properly.
2. **Test.** Is it working the way it normally is? If it isn't, then you probably have a corrupt download.

If neither of the above steps fix your problem,

3. **Bug reports.** I have checked, but it dosen't seen anyone else has filed a bug report for this. A second set of eyes helps! :-) Create a launchpad account if you don't already have one, and report a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bugs.

Comment: Fails on multiple machines using an automate process we have used for months.

Unfortunately,  I can't log in to the support site to create a bug right now.  :-(

Comment: What's the sha256sum result from your system?

Comment: Sorry, I don't currently have access to an Ubuntu system currently.

Answer (score 0):

Addressed under: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1699396, See bug for details.